# How to get data from a two way data-binded object

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, ionic2

**Issue**

When I put data into the input fields the click function logs

```
{
  Name:"",
  Pass:""
}
```

I want to get the object data.

**Code**

I have a login screen with two inputs and a login button. I want to two way databind an object `user: User` to the inputs and on click have access to the `user` object properties `Name` and `Pass`.

Here's the html page

```
<ion-content padding class="ion-content">

  <ion-list>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text" [(value)]="user.Name" placeholder="username"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="password" [(value)]="user.Pass" placeholder="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

  <div padding>
    <button ion-button color="primary" block (click)="login($event);">Sign In</button>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

and here is my the corresponding .ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class User{
    public Name: String;
    public Pass: String;
    constructor(){
        this.Name = "";
        this.Pass = "";
    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'login-page',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

  user: User;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
      this.user = new User();
  }

  login(){
      console.log(this.user);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that if you will use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[(value)]` it will work exactly as you wish.